# Why -1%26 = -1 in Java and C, and why it is 25 in Python?

Tags: java, python, c, modulo

Why modulo operator is not working as intended in C and Java?

Comment: Remainder vs modulus

Comment: I much prefer the remainder version, but in java the design decision was made differently :-(

Comment: Because negative % something is implementation defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's %-operator calculates the mathematical remainder, not the modulus. The remainder is by definition a number between 0 and the divisor, it doesn't depend on the sign of the dividend like the modulus.

Comment: Actually, you've got it backward.  If y is positive, then "x mod y" will be between 0 and y-1, while the sign of "x remainder y" will depend upon that of x.  I can't think of any occasions where I've ever used the "%" operator on a negative number and wanted the remainder, but for a long time the standard only mandated particular behavior for "%" with positive operands; in those cases "mod" and "remainder" were synonymous, and "mod" was easier to say, so that's the name that stuck.

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) has a nice table which shows the sign of the operation for various languages. In Python it is the sign of the divisor (26), in Java/C the sign of the dividend (-1).

Answer (score 1):

It is working as specified.

The contract is that

```
a == (a/b) * b + (a % b)
```

and integer division truncates toward zero. So with a negative dividend, you get a negative remainder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python but `%` operator in java returns the remainder obtained after the division.

```
-1%26
```

breaking it down:

```
            26)-1(0
                0
                ---
                -1 ---> Remainder as (-1+0=-1)
```